# Ios Extract data using regex from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

i have

```
NSString *str =  @"<0x112233><0x112233><0x112233>0a";
```

i want this data to be saved in nsarray

```
nsarray  : { 0x112233 0x112233 0x112233 }
```

only save data which is enclosed in "<>" and ignore all other.

i tried regex like this

```
NSString *str =  @"<0x112233><0x112233><0x112233>0a";

NSError *error2;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<(.*)>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error2];
if (error2)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [error2 description]);
}

NSArray *payloadRanges=[regex matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];


NSLog(@"data %@",payloadRanges);
```

but i gives me this output:

```
data (
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x1ddc5e30>{0, 30}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x1f078710> <(.*)> 0x1}"
)
```

Comment: "Extract data using regex from string" - **please don't.** Use `NSScanner` or something sane. No regexes for this.

Comment: You may wish to make your regular expression non-greedy and ignore the angle brackets - try:
    (?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)

Comment: [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@" "]];

Comment: @Martin R answer solved my problem . thanks kumar kl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(As Pat Teen said in a comment), your pattern is *greedy*,
which means that the first match gets as much as possible, which is the entire string.

You can fix that by changing the pattern `@"<(.*)>"` to `@"<(.*?)>"`.

Then `payloadRanges` is an array of three `NSTextCheckingResult` objects:

```
(
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010af40>{0, 10}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x100108960> <(.*?)> 0x1}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010c210>{10, 10}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x100108960> <(.*?)> 0x1}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x10010c250>{20, 10}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x100108960> <(.*?)> 0x1}"
)
```

Now you have to extract the substring matching the `(...)` group from each result:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in payloadRanges) {
    [data addObject:[str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]];
}
NSLog(@"data %@",data);
```

Output:

```
data (
    0x112233,
    0x112233,
    0x112233
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool , Try this simple line of manually hardcoded without using of any reg exper.:

```
NSString *convert =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

    convert= [convert stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"con %@",convert);
    NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[convert componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%@" ,array);

    for(NSString *str in array){
        if([str length]<4){
            [array removeObject:str];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Comment: put the loop for the array . and check for every object of it has minimum length if not just remove the object from the array.

Comment: (
    "",
    0x112233,
    "",
    0x112233,
    "",
    0x112233,
    0a
) and some empty strings also

Comment: con  0x112233 0x112233 0x1122330a
2013-10-26 16:35:48.896 GCDtest1[729:907] (
    "",
    0x112233,
    0x112233,
    0x1122330a
)   no no 0a should be ignored

Comment: currently 0a is at last position but it can be anywhere in string

Comment: 0x112233, whatever you want that should be the legnth arround 8 .. right

Comment: but if 0a comes inside lessthan greater than , than its fine let it come. other wise ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
NSString *str =  @"<0x112233><0x112233><0x112233>0a";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];

    NSString *str1 = [arr lastObject];

    NSArray *arr1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@">"];

    NSLog(@"array is %@",arr1);

    NSString *str2 = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:0] substringFromIndex:1];

NSString *str3=[str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0a" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"str3 is %@",str3);
[yourArray addObject:str3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another regex that should work with your requirements:

```
<([^>]*)>
```